# How should I format whispered dialog?

Tags: writing, dialogue, story

How do would you write out character whispering in a narrative story, would you use italics, parantheses, maybe dependent on variety of styles?

Comment: "What's going on?" Mary whispered.

Comment: {{{{however you want to}}}

Answer (score 1):

From what I've seen, most authors use italics for two main reasons (though there are a variety of other uses):

1) emphasizing a point in the narration

> It's not that he had *wanted* to kill the man--he had no choice in the matter.

2) distinguishing a character's *thoughts* from their literal dialog

> "Have fun!" I smiled and waved until my parents pulled out of the driveway and were out of sight. *Now the fun begins.*

I haven't personally seen authors use italics to indicate whispering. You could introduce the dialog regularly and then indicate that it was spoken in a whisper:

> "Are they gone?" she whispered, peering through the blinds.

However, there's nothing stopping you from doing the following:

> "*Are they gone?*"
>
> "I think so."

Note how the italics of one speaker's dialog stands in contrast to the regular formatting of the other speaker's dialog. A reader will naturally interpret the first line as softly spoken or whispered.